# Delete query error for multiple records

Tags: mysql

I have a problem in this query:

```
string sqlString = "DELETE FROM [upload_news] WHERE (SELECT TOP " + no_of_recordss + " * FROM [upload_news] WHERE [country]='" + countryy.Text + "')";
```

Error Message :

> Error: {"An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context
>   where a condition is expected, near ')'."}

How can i fix this ?

Comment: And you're sure that this is MySQL?

Comment: post your table structure

Comment: You need an exprssion in the where clause. Moreover AFAIK MySQL doesn't support select top <NUM_RECORDS>, you have to use limit, but limit is not working in a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

In the where clause you need a boolean expression.
Moreover, mysql doesn't support select top, you have to use limit instead and you can use it directly on delete

So your query should be:

```
delete from upload_news 
    where country=<SOME_COUNTRY> limit <NO_OF_RECORDS>
```

You have to replace values within "<>" with your desired values.

Or in your "strange" syntax:

```
string sqlString = "DELETE FROM [upload_news] WHERE [country]='" + countryy.Text + "' limit "+no_of_recordss;
```

Comment: If you can add your details about your table structure I can refine the answer.